# The requested package is unknown

Tags: errors, packages, package-options, compilation-error, ragged2e

I used these packages:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{color}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
```

Every time I run the Tex editor I get a message The requested package is unknown then details name="ragged2e" and after this window there is a window for intalling ragged2e.sty. I click install and this occurs again and again. How I get rid of it?
Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: There is a ragged2e package and it goes by that name (sometimes packages are bundled together).  Very few packages require it.  Sidenotes is one, so sidecap (not installed on my computer) might be another.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to isntall it wilt \usepackage{ragged2e} but I get this error
Unfortunately, the package ragged2e could not be installed

I added the package in the current tex folder but it didn't work :(