# Problem with ragged2e

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, align, ragged2e

I want to use justifying command from this package but it could not be installed.
Everytime I use `\usepackage{ragged2e}` I get this error:

> File `ragged2e.sty' not found. \usepackage.

How could I install it or align the text another way? 
It's beamer presentation

Comment: Which tex distribution do you use? miktex, texlive,...?

Comment: Please also clarify how this current question is different from your previous one [The requested package is unknown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/517330/134144)

Comment: you should be able to install ragged2e via miktex or texlive package manager but justifying is the default, there are almost no circumstances where `\justifying`  is useful, why do you think you need it?

Comment: I am using texstudio. I cannot use \justifying without ragged2e. I am asking for another way to align text, that is why this question is different than the previous one.

Comment: texstudio is not relevant, that is just the editor you use to write the file it does not affect tex's behaviour. But why do you want t use `\justifying`  justified text is the default so if it is not justifying it is because you have specified a command to stop that. So  if you what justified text, the thing to do is not use `\raggedright` or `\centering` at that point. You never need `\justifying`

Comment: I am using beamer environment. When I use documentclass article, the text is justified but it is not justified in beamer.